# Java: How to keep looping to fix an exception?

Tags: java, loops, exception, try-catch

Is there a way to keep looping in a try catch until the exception is fixed?

For example:

```
try{
//something
}
catch(SomeException e){
  //display error message 'an exception occurred try again'
  //go back to try statement
}
```

After writing out the above pseudocode, I thought of a possible solution, although I think it going to be frowned upon...would a GOTO statement be okay for this case, if there is no other way? 
I have never used one and have been taught to stay away from it as much as possible...but this actually seems a case where it can be used.
If there is a better way, then please shine some light onto me.

Comment: Goto would work, but an explicit loop would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop and retry count strategy you can prevent `goto`.

Something like:

```
int MAX_RETRY = 10
int retryCount = 0
while(retryCount < MAX_RETRY){
    try{
        //something
    }
    catch(SomeException e){
        //display error message 'an exception occurred try again'
        //go back to try statement
        retryCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: how could I do this without a max limit?

Comment: @bobdylan You want to do it infintely? You can change the condition to `while(true)` but I would not suggest to do that.